# The Microsoft access database engine cannot open or write to the file Permission Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

Before I specify my problem, let me tell you all that I've already explored enough on this issue over internet but none of any article help me to solve my issue. The problem is, When I try to upload an excel file and start processing it it throws an error **"The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file . It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data"**. My code is working properly on my local machine the main issue comes when i upload code to the production server.
Below is my code:

```
   if (file_Upload_DataFile.HasFile)
            {
                string fileName = 
    Path.GetFileName(file_Upload_DataFile.PostedFile.FileName);
                    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file_Upload_DataFile.PostedFile.FileName);

                    if (fileExtension != ".xls" && fileExtension != ".xlsx")
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "onload", "alert('invalid file format!! you must upload a file having an extention of either (.xls) or (.xlsx)');", true);
                        extFlag = false;
                    }

                    string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("../ExcelReport/" + fileName);
                    file_Upload_DataFile.SaveAs(fileLocation);
                    if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                    {
                        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        extFlag = true;
                    }
                    else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        extFlag = true;
                    }

                }
                if (extFlag != false)
                {

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
                    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
                    con.Close();
    }
```

**Note: I'm using MySql as database.**

I've also set the permissions to the folder on my server where the file get stored after uploading still the same issue.

Comment: Does the user account running the ASP.NET process have access to the folder?

Comment: Nope, the user do not have permissions

Comment: I mean the server account, not the client user...

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams for reply,  According to the project requirement I've created a folder to save the excel files uploaded by user and also set the permission of read/write

Comment: Who did you set the permissions for though?  "Everyone" ?

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1929989.aspx?The+Microsoft+Office+Access+database+engine+cannot+open+or+write+to+the+file+

Comment: I've created a new user named Network Service and set permission to it. I've taken the reference for this from this link https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/01/c-microsoft-office-access-database.html

Comment: Are you running your ASP.NET processes as that same user? Try temporarily setting "read" for "Everyone" on the folder and see if that changes things.